Same ACS URL, Different Binding
If the SP Metadata contains same ACS URL but with different bindings and index, do I need to add all of them in Okta?
For example:
<AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://sts.contoso.com/adfs/ls/" index="0" isDefault="true" />
    <AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact" Location="https://sts.contoso.com/adfs/ls/" index="1" /> 
    <AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://sts.contoso.com/adfs/ls/" index="2" /> 

I am wondering if I can just add "https://sts.contoso.com/adfs/ls/" in the SSO URL field since all the URLs are same.

No, you can add just one ACS URL into Okta, it will be OK.
SP metadata tells a counterparty, that it supports different bindings/URLs (potentially). But because they are all the same URL in your case, that mean that you are safe to configure Okta with it.
In a situation where "Redirect" is URL1, but "Post" is URL2, then you need to be careful what to configure in Okta (or any other SAML IdP), because it may support only one specific method. For example, your IdP can only do "POST", but you take SP "Redirect" URL and configure it in your IdP, this won't work.
